# SQL query issue (with screenshot)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
Shop
Shop_id  City_id   Address  
1        1         Address 1      
2        1         Address 2
3        2         Address 3 
4        2         Address 4
5        1         Address 5
6        1         Address 6

City
City_id  Name
1        Vilnius
2        Kaunas

Places
Place_id  Shop_id  Book_id
1         3        1
2         2        1
3         3        2
4         4        3
5         3        3
```

In `Places` table I save shops where you can buy specific book.
Also I have checkboxes form:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT places.place_id, places.book_id, places.shop_id,
shop.shop_id, shop.city_id,shop.address,city.city_id,city.name 
FROM shop INNER JOIN places ON places.shop_id=shop.shop_id 
INNER JOIN city ON shop.city_id=city.city_id") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        echo '<tr> 
                <td><input type="checkbox"'; if ($row['book_id']==$id2){echo 'checked';}echo' name="identifer[]" value="'.$row['shop_id'].'" /> <br /></td>  
                <td>'.ucfirst($row['Name']).','.$row['Address'].' </td> 
             </tr>
```

I'm trying to create table with **all** available shops with checbox checked value if `Book_id` equal to `$id2`. 
To be more clear here is the screenshot, it shows what I get from my code:

[image]

Obviously, it basically write down all shops from `Places` table. I'm trying to change my  SQL code, but I can't get it right, so I need help.

Comment: Do you want to list `all shops` or `all places`? Multiple places per shop! You text tells a different story from your query.

Comment: @omg_ponies: Why would you delete the [query] tag? The query is the point of the question.

Comment: "query" is too generic; it's been my habit to remove the tag.  If the query is your issue, the combination of "sql" and "mysql" should be far more popular (means more are likely to see your question & answer).

Comment: @OMGPonies: I created a chatroom. Would you mind a quick chat? Will be around for like 15 min, in case you don't get this in time .. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5040/chat1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is not solved with a `LEFT JOIN`, because then you *can* get multiple `Places` per `Shop`. Try this:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM places p
               WHERE  p.shop_id = s.shop_id AND p.Book_id = $id2) AS has_book
      ,s.shop_id, s.city_id, s.address
      ,c.city_id, c.name 
FROM   shop s
JOIN   city c USING (city_id)  -- or LEFT JOIN if city could be missing
```

---

Or, if `(Shop_id, Book_id)` is guaranteed to be unique - meaning a book can never appear more than once in a shop - *and* you want to include columns from `Places`, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT p.place_id, p.book_id, p.shop_id
      ,s.shop_id, s.city_id, s.address
      ,c.city_id, c.name 
FROM   shop s
JOIN   city c USING (city_id)  -- or LEFT JOIN if city could be missing
LEFT   JOIN places p ON p.shop_id = s.shop_id AND p.Book_id = $id2
```

Note the additional condition in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`. Must be there, not in a `WHERE` clause.
That gives you *every* shop and appends data for a place *only* if it has the book. As a shop can have every book only once, *no shop* will be doubled.

Comment: Thank you! Query is working good, but I'm not sure how I have to use `has_book` ?

Comment: @Lina: `has_book` is boolean (0 or 1 in mysql) and would be the check mark in your screenshot. `TRUE` / `1` would mean "check", `FALSE` or `0` means "not checked".

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an INNER JOIN on both tables. That means the query will return records where there's data on BOTH sides of the join only. Your Places table lists only shops 2,3,4. So records with ID 1,5,6 in the Shops table will not be returned, because there's no matching Places record.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your INNER JOINS with LEFT JOINS

Comment: I tried, but than it returns all shops + shop, which shop_id is 3 - three times.

Answer (score 0):

`Shop LEFT JOIN Places LEFT JOIN City` and `GROUP BY shop_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass query of id2 into your query? If am understanding your question properly:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT places.place_id, places.book_id, places.shop_id,
shop.shop_id, shop.city_id,shop.address,city.city_id,city.name 
FROM shop INNER JOIN places ON places.shop_id=shop.shop_id 
INNER JOIN city ON shop.city_id=city.city_id
AND places.Place_id='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($id2));

$result = mysql_query($query);
```